# Express/EJS - if it's a specific view file thats rendered do something

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a view that is:

`/views/signup.html`

I want to have different elements on the page in my main layout template depending on what view is loading.

In my main layout file, when that specific view is rendered I want to do something like:

```
  <% if (ecomHeader) { %>
    <% include includes/signup-nav.html %>
  <% } %>
  <% else { %>
    <% include includes/nav.html %>
  <% } %>
```

This obviously doesn't work

```
ReferenceError: ../views/layout.html:9
    7| </head>

    8| <body>

 >> 9|   <% if (ecomHeader) { %>

    10|     <% include includes/signup-nav.html %>

    11|   <% } else { %>

    12|     <% include includes/nav.html %>
```

Can you do that? is that how that works?

render code:

```
...
let token = createCSRFToken(req);
let ecomHeader = true;
res.render('premium/signup', {
  message: req.flash('signupMessage'),
  token: token,
  ecomHeader: true
});
...
```

There is a exports. thing that wraps this, not sure if thats relevant or not

Comment: `res.render('signup', { signup: true })` or `signup: false` depending on who is rendering?

Comment: could you post your render code?

Comment: I just did hope it helps

Comment: you're rendering `premium/signup` not `layout.html`, so you cannot pass variables to `layout.html`? maybe change the structure of signup to include the partials?

Answer (score 0):

You're else condition is missing certain things. Make sure you pass signup: true/false boolean from the back-end to your views.

```
res.render("main-template", {
    signup: true/false
});
```

Then in your html, you need to do this - Make sure you use `<%-`.

```
<% if(signup){ %>
   <%- include('includes/signup-nav.html'); %>
 <% } else { %>  
   <%- include('includes/nav.html'); %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Okay so I do that but it tells me `signup is undefined` do I have to declare it as a variable somewhere else?

Comment: You are not rendering views/layout.html. You are rendering premium/signup. And `{
  message: req.flash('signupMessage'),
  token: token,
  signup: true/false,
  ecomHeader: true
}` - Signup should be passed here.

Comment: if you find my solution helpful, please accept and upvote :) Thanks!